# Typo3 crashed after installing extension: Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error, parse-error, typo3-7.6.x

I'm running Typo3 7.6 and foolishly tried an out of date extension on my site. I got one error, tried to uninstall the extension and that just made things worse. Now the whole system is crashed from back and front with this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   /html/typo3/typo3_src-7.6.10/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/ExtensionManagementUtility.php
>   on line 1654

Not sure what it wants me to do with this information.

Here's my code in **ExtensionManagementUtility.php on line 1654**:

```
    /**
 * Execute ext_localconf.php files from extensions
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function loadSingleExtLocalconfFiles()
{
    // This is the main array meant to be manipulated in the ext_localconf.php files
    // In general it is recommended to not rely on it to be globally defined in that
    // scope but to use $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] instead.
    // Nevertheless we define it here as global for backwards compatibility.
    global $TYPO3_CONF_VARS;
    foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_LOADED_EXT'] as $_EXTKEY => $extensionInformation) {
        if ((is_array($extensionInformation) || $extensionInformation instanceof \ArrayAccess) && isset($extensionInformation['ext_localconf.php'])) {
            // $_EXTKEY and $_EXTCONF are available in ext_localconf.php
            // and are explicitly set in cached file as well
            $_EXTCONF = isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf'][$_EXTKEY]) ? $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf'][$_EXTKEY] : null;
            require $extensionInformation['ext_localconf.php'];
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get out of this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to recover your installation you need to deactivate that new extension.

you can try to do it in the install tool (just call your-domain.tld/typo3/install/): in the area "Important Actions" you can find the option **Check for broken extensions**

or you do it by hand: edit `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`, search that extension and change the state from `active` to `inactive`. then clear all caches!

afterwards you can remove the extension.

Comment: Yes!  Bernd Wilke πφ, that did the trick.
I had to do it by hand because there was no way to access the CMS.
Thanks for the simple instruction for a fairly easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem comes from one of the included files, i.e. the configuration of one of your extensions. I don’t get why PHP does not display the actual file name then, but well… lets try to fix it:

To get the filename, insert a line before `require…` to output it:

```
echo $_EXTKEY, " ", $extensionInformation['ext_localconf.php'], "\n";
require $extensionInformation['ext_localconf.php'];
```

After a reload, you should see a list of extension keys and file names, with the last one being the one causing the trouble.